Ktor HttpClient refreshTokens not firing on 401
I'm having some trouble with Ktor in a Kotlin app I am writing. I have followed the directions here https://ktor.io/docs/client-bearer-auth.html#example-oauth-google for what I assume is a pretty standard authentication flow, only modified such that it authenticates against a keycloak server and a Ktor HttpClient is injected into another api handler class of mine, e.g. ApiClient, using Hilt.
Logging into my app works like this: the user logs in using ApiClient.authenticate(), which sets my tokens. This all seems to be valid. The app then immediately authorizes the user by fetching their roles using ApiClient.authorize(), which requires the access token for bearer authentication that we just set in the previous step. This seems to be valid as well.
Once in the application, the user can open an activity Foo whose viewmodel FooViewModel calls ApiClient.getFoo() on init. This works fine, unless more than maybe 10 minutes have elapsed, where I receive a io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException with a 401 response status. The only reason this makes sense is because Kotlin is clearly trying to deserialize a 401 response into a List<FooDTO> object, but I don't understand why it's blowing up on the 401 response in the first place.
As you can see in DIModules.kt, my ApiClient is configured to be injected with a Ktor HttpClient, and this HttpClient is configured to refresh the access token automatically. As far as I can tell, this has never happened in my application.
Can anyone knowledgeable about these methods of authentication help me out? I feel a bit lost in the sauce as I keep reading and rereading Ktor's documentation, and it's still not clear to me where my bug is.
For more context, this keycloak server is not set up to require a client secret. The access tokens expire in 300s, and the refresh tokens expire in 1800s.
ApiClient.kt
class ApiClient @Inject constructor(
    val prefs: PrefsManager,
    val httpClient: HttpClient
) {
    // initializing our tokens
    suspend fun authenticate(username: String, password: String) : TokenInfo {
        try {
            val res : TokenInfo = httpClient.submitForm(
                url = "${prefs.siteURL}${prefs.authRoute}/token",
                parameters {
                    append("client_id", prefs.clientId!!)
                    append("username", username)
                    append("password", password)
                    append("grant_type", "password")
                    append("scope", "openid")
                }
            ).body()

            TokenStorage.tokens.add(BearerTokens(res.accessToken, res.refreshToken ?: ""))

            return res
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            throw HttpClientException("Authentication Error: ${e.message ?: "Unexpected error occurred"}")
        }
    }
    
    // getting a protected resource requiring a bearer token
    suspend fun authorize() : RoleResponse {
        val res = httpClient.get("${prefs.siteURL}${prefs.authRoute}/userinfo?")

        try {
            return res.body<RoleResponse>()
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            throw HttpClientException("Authorization Error: ${e.message ?: "Unexpected error occurred"}")
        }
    }
    
    // getting another protected resource requiring a bearer token
    suspend fun fetchFoo(): List<FooDTO> {
        return httpClient.get("${prefs.siteURL}/fooendpoint").body<List<FooDTO>>()
    }
}

FooViewModel.kt
init {
    try {
        isLoading = true
        
        apiClient.fetchFoo()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // handle exception
    } finally {
        isLoading = false
    }
}

DIModules.kt
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ApiClientModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiClient(prefs: PrefsManager) : ApiClient {
        val httpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
            expectSuccess = false

            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(Json{
                    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                    isLenient = true
                })
            }

            install(HttpTimeout) {
                requestTimeoutMillis = 8000
            }

            install(Auth) {
                bearer {
                    loadTokens {
                        TokenStorage.tokens.last()
                    }
                    sendWithoutRequest { request ->
                        request.url.host == "${prefs.siteURL}${prefs.authRoute}"
                    }
                    refreshTokens {
                        val refreshTokenInfo: TokenInfo = client.submitForm(
                            url = "${prefs.siteURL}${prefs.authRoute}/token",
                            formParameters = parameters {
                                append("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                                append("client_id", prefs.clientId!!)
                                append("refresh_token", oldTokens?.refreshToken ?: "")
                            }
                        ) { markAsRefreshTokenRequest() }.body()
                        TokenStorage.tokens.add(BearerTokens(refreshTokenInfo.accessToken, oldTokens?.refreshToken!!))
                        TokenStorage.tokens.last()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ApiClient(prefs, httpClient)
    }
}

TokenStorage.kt
object TokenStorage {
    val tokens = mutableListOf<BearerTokens>()
}

TokenInfo.kt
@Serializable
data class TokenInfo(
    @SerialName("access_token") val accessToken: String,
    @SerialName("expires_in") val expiresIn: Int,
    @SerialName("refresh_token") val refreshToken: String? = null,
    val scope: String,
    @SerialName("token_type") val tokenType: String,
    @SerialName("id_token") val idToken: String,
)


Can you please check the conditions for refreshing the token (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71123850/13963150)?

This is interesting. None of the response headers from any of my endpoints contain WWW-Authenticate. It's unclear to me how any of the protected  resource endpoints require a bearer token without supplying this header if that's how it's supposed to work. Otherwise, what you see in my post is sort of what you get. I'm definitely getting a 401, and I have no knowledge of circuitBreaker. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding.
